# Cron jobs and php scripts

Tags: php, bash, cron

So, i have a script that calls 2 other scripts that back up devices.

Problem is, If i call the main script manually that opens up the other two in a screen session, everything works fine. 
The 2 scripts it calls basically sends data to an sql server via a php script.

IE 
I have the line

```
$link = mysql_connect("server ip", "username", "password", "database");
```

Running manually (Which runs from my user directory) it works fine.

If i have the cron job run, it will run fine to a point when it gets to the php section of the script it gets the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /export/home/myname/my_Scripts/php_script_its_running
```

So, being that it works correctly if i manually run it, and not when i run it via cron, I am assuming it is either running a different php instance due to it being run by cron or something oddball like that? or, idk, not 100% familiar with cron jobs yet.

So while i was debugging it more, it looks to be using a different version of php than what my user account is using, 5.1 comparred to 5.4

Not sure if there is an easy way to change it to use my user accounts php setup? Unfortunately i have no root access to the box.

Answer
So, i ran a working script, and added phpinfo(), grabbed the path information and added that to the cronjob so it would overwrite the defaults.

so the top of the cronjob file looks something like

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH = /usr/kerberos/bin:/app/php-5.4.3/bin

Comment: if unsure, you can schedule cron job with 'which php' to see if it's the right instance. I would also check permissions on your scripts (or just set them to 777 for testing if permissions is the problem).

Comment: This was a nice night, figured it out after i posted the question, will edit the question if anyone else has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Answer So, i ran a working script, and added phpinfo(), grabbed the path information and added that to the cronjob so it would overwrite the defaults.

so the top of the cronjob file looks something like

SHELL=/bin/bash PATH = /usr/kerberos/bin:/app/php-5.4.3/bin